# data.table::fread issue with new lines in text

Tags: r, data.table, fread

I am having issues with data.table::fread. Please see below first problematic file and the result of reading it with fread and second a file that is read without any problems correctly.

```
# Test data.table::fread on following data with two new lines after Trust and before CEF
textProblem <- "Ticker;FullName;NorgateID;IsIndex;MarketID;Market;GroupID;Group;IndustryID;Industry;GicsID;GicsCategoryName;IcbID;IcbCategoryName;trbccode;trbcname;gicscode;gicsname;indexsymbol1;indexsymbol2;indexsymbol3;indexsymbol4;DelistingDate;PointValue;MarginDeposit;RoundLotSize;TickSize
TFA-200101;Morgan Stanley Dean Witter Municipal Income Trust

 CEF;265990;0;14;US Delisted Stocks;2;Investment Company;0;Unassigned or n/a;;;;;n/a;n/a;n/a;n/a;;;;;2001-01-23;1;0;0;0"

as.data.frame(data.table::fread(input=textProblem, sep=";", na.strings=c("Unassigned or n/a", "n/a", "{EMPTY}")))

textWorking <- "Ticker;FullName;NorgateID;IsIndex;MarketID;Market;GroupID;Group;IndustryID;Industry;GicsID;GicsCategoryName;IcbID;IcbCategoryName;trbccode;trbcname;gicscode;gicsname;indexsymbol1;indexsymbol2;indexsymbol3;indexsymbol4;DelistingDate;PointValue;MarginDeposit;RoundLotSize;TickSize
&6J_CCB;Japanese Yen Continuous Futures Backadjusted;687021;0;77;CME Group;32;Currency Futures;0;Unassigned or n/a;;;;;n/a;n/a;n/a;n/a;;;;;{EMPTY};125000;2200;1;5e-005"

as.data.frame(data.table::fread(input=textWorking, sep=";", na.strings=c("Unassigned or n/a", "n/a", "{EMPTY}")))
```

The output on my system:

```
> # Test data.table::fread on following data with two new lines after Trust and before CEF
> textProblem <- "Ticker;FullName;NorgateID;IsIndex;MarketID;Market;GroupID;Group;IndustryID;Industry;GicsID;GicsCategoryName;IcbID;IcbCategoryName;trbccode;trbcname;gicscode;gicsname;indexsymbol1;indexsymbol2;indexsymbol3;indexsymbol4;DelistingDate;PointValue;MarginDeposit;RoundLotSize;TickSize
+ TFA-200101;Morgan Stanley Dean Witter Municipal Income Trust
+ 
+  CEF;265990;0;14;US Delisted Stocks;2;Investment Company;0;Unassigned or n/a;;;;;n/a;n/a;n/a;n/a;;;;;2001-01-23;1;0;0;0"
> 
> as.data.frame(data.table::fread(input=textProblem, sep=";", na.strings=c("Unassigned or n/a", "n/a", "{EMPTY}")))
   V1     V2 V3 V4                 V5 V6                 V7 V8 V9 V10 V11 V12 V13 V14 V15 V16 V17 V18 V19 V20 V21        V22 V23 V24 V25 V26
1 CEF 265990  0 14 US Delisted Stocks  2 Investment Company  0 NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA 2001-01-23   1   0   0   0
> 
> textWorking <- "Ticker;FullName;NorgateID;IsIndex;MarketID;Market;GroupID;Group;IndustryID;Industry;GicsID;GicsCategoryName;IcbID;IcbCategoryName;trbccode;trbcname;gicscode;gicsname;indexsymbol1;indexsymbol2;indexsymbol3;indexsymbol4;DelistingDate;PointValue;MarginDeposit;RoundLotSize;TickSize
+ &6J_CCB;Japanese Yen Continuous Futures Backadjusted;687021;0;77;CME Group;32;Currency Futures;0;Unassigned or n/a;;;;;n/a;n/a;n/a;n/a;;;;;{EMPTY};125000;2200;1;5e-005"
> 
> as.data.frame(data.table::fread(input=textWorking, sep=";", na.strings=c("Unassigned or n/a", "n/a", "{EMPTY}")))
   Ticker                                     FullName NorgateID IsIndex MarketID    Market GroupID            Group IndustryID Industry GicsID GicsCategoryName IcbID IcbCategoryName trbccode trbcname gicscode gicsname indexsymbol1 indexsymbol2
1 &6J_CCB Japanese Yen Continuous Futures Backadjusted    687021       0       77 CME Group      32 Currency Futures          0       NA     NA               NA    NA              NA       NA       NA       NA       NA           NA           NA
  indexsymbol3 indexsymbol4 DelistingDate PointValue MarginDeposit RoundLotSize TickSize
1           NA           NA            NA     125000          2200            1    5e-05

> sessionInfo()
R version 3.4.4 (2018-03-15)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /usr/lib/openblas-base/libblas.so.3
LAPACK: /usr/lib/libopenblasp-r0.2.18.so

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8   
 [6] LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8    LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                  LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.4.4    tools_3.4.4       yaml_2.1.19       data.table_1.11.2
```

Comment: minor tip -- `fread` has a `data.table` argument which you can toggle to return a `data.frame` automatically

Comment: I'm not sure what you're expected output is?

Comment: I guess you're expecting that `Morgan Stanley Dean Witter Municipal Income Trust\n\n CEF` be treated as a single field entry

Comment: This can be fixed by making sure this text field is quoted like `"Morgan Stanley Dean Witter Municipal Income Trust\n\n CEF"`. If you have control over the program that created this file, please ensure to quote this text field. I think it's quite difficult to deal with the embedded newline here, otherwise, in terms of creating a general rule. You might try [filing an issue](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues) anyway, I seem to recall a similar problem arising recently.